# page-break-inside:avoid does not work as expected in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-multicolumn-layout

I have some legacy code that I am working on that utilizes `column-count: 2` with a `break-inside` / `page-break-inside` of `avoid` on the child elements.

This works as expected when there is more than 1 child, but when there is only one child, the element gets split into the two columns on Firefox. On chrome, the one element is contained to the first column as expected.

I made a codepen to demonstrate this issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrbEZY
Compare the differences in Chrome vs Firefox to understand what I am talking about.

All the resources I can find about this, say that Firefox has supported `page-break-inside` since Firefox 19.

Is there something else I am missing here to resolve this issue without completely rewriting my codebase?

Answer (score 4):

Specifying `.child { overflow: hidden; }` fixes this, but feels like a bit of a hack.

Comment: That does feel like a bit of a hack, but it might be the cleanest solution for this I have seen so far. The solution that I came up with involved setting the child to `display: table;` which also seems like a hack.

Comment: Very nice! I have the same problem in FF, Edge. Here is example link on quickatit.com https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_break-inside.cfm